# How do I write a MySQL query that looks for elements whose keys are in a PHP array?

Tags: php, mysql

One of the conditions for my query is that one of table.id should belong to the array $table_arr. Is there a way that will allow me to implement this? Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your question?  Are you saying that the column value table.id must exist within $table_arr?  Where is $table_arr coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing `$table_arr` is a PHP array of ints or strings.

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (".implode(", ", $table_arr).")";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysql, $query);

    // etc
```